# How to remove persistent "Mi Band is Connected" notification in Android?

Tags: notification-bar, xiaomi, push-notifications

I have Mi band 2 from *Xiaomi,* always connected to my Android device for fitness activity tracking. In the notification drawer, there is always a persistent(unclearable notification) - "Mi Band is/isn't connected - which is annoying. Is there any way I could make it disappear and receive other notifications from the Mi Fit App, if any?

Comment: Do you have the right to move this question to move there?

Answer (score 24):

**Profile -> Settings -> Show Status in Notification Shade**

- August 2018
- Android version 8.0
- MiFit App version 3.4.4

---

[image: Profile -> Settings]

[image: Settings -> Show Status in Notification Shade]

Comment: Just to note, I used this to "fix" an annoying feature of Mii Fit, where there was ALWAYS a badge on the icon, to show a notification.  Obviously the notification was that the band was connected, but it was driving me mad trying to clear the number and make my home screen "clean".

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, in Mi Fit application at the Profile -> My Devices -> Mi Band 2 exist special option for this notification.
Unfortunatelly, right now I'm using Mi Fit at IOS and cannot check it, but earlier I switched this notification off, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: No, there is no such option under the devices option.

Comment: It is there :) Check: Status -> Setup -> Show status ....

Comment: Please mention the full location of the option. Thanks.